# Auto join Game Groups

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-game-groups

I'm checking the api for [game groups](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/app-game-groups) and it looks fine but I would like to know if in this mode its possible that when a user joins a group, it is inmediately added as a member of the group, or if it will always require that the admin of the group confirms the joining.

What we want is to create groups and make the people enter and use the groups but only using the app, without the need of the admin to accept the requests.

Answer (score 0):

In version 1, the API call has the ability to set the admin when creating the group.

In version 2, the caller of the create dialog is automatically added as an admin.